# python regex deletes everything in a dataframe column and shouldnt be

Tags: python, pandas

Im looking to write a python function with regex that will remove all text within parenthesis AND any numeric values from the same string. I'd like to apply this function to Column1 in my pandas dataframe. Below is where I got to, however when I run the code all strings disappear and I end up with essentially an empty Column1. any idea what Im doing wrong..column1 is just text with some () and some numbers data

```
import re
    def delParenthesis(stringToReplace):
        re.sub(r'\([^()]*\)|[0-9]','', stringToReplace)

    df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].apply(delParenthesis)
```

Comment: Please add example on which your code does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) expects the applied function to return its result.

```
import re
def delParenthesis(stringToReplace):
    return re.sub(r'\([^()]*\)|[0-9]','', stringToReplace)

df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].apply(delParenthesis)
```